# Convert Ionic.Zip with reference to assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i want to convert my code in Ionic.Zip to assembly because for some reason i dont want to reference it. Heres the code with the reference.

```
ZipFile zipFileToExtract = ZipFile.Read(ziploc);
zipFileToExtract.ExtractAll(Server.MapPath("~/ExtractedFiles/"), ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverwrite);
```

Now i want to convert it using assembly.

```
 Assembly _assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(strDllPath);
 var instance = _assembly.CreateInstance("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile");
 Type type = _assembly.GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1}", "Ionic.Zip", "ZipFile"));

 object zipFileToExtract = type.InvokeMember("Read",
            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, instance, new Object[] { _zipFilELocation });
var xField = zipFileToExtract.GetType().GetField("ExtractAll", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

xField.SetValue(zipFileToExtract, new Object[] { destination, , "Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverwrite" });
```

I want to access the **zipFileToExtract** and call the **ExtractAll()** but i dont know how to do it. I already search multiple times but i cant find the right solution. Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.